# Return val() of selector from lodash filter method

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have the following code:

```
_.filter($('.date-field'), function(n) { return n.val() });
```

where n is supposed to be the selected elements:

```
<input class="date-field" id="return-date" placeholder="return date" type="text" value="xyz">
```

I want to get the value of each element with class `.date-field` but when I do `n.val()`. It returns error:

> Uncaught TypeError: n.val() is not a function

What should I do?

Comment: try to use return  $(this).val()

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: Why don't you use the jQuery `filter` method? Why do you even use the `filter` method if you just want to get the values? If you want to create an array of values, use `map`, if you want to iterate use the `each` method.

Comment: How shall I do it with `jquery`?

Comment: try console.log($(this)) and console.log(n) and check what values it has

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_.filter` is used for filtering a collection of N elements to another collection of N or less elements.

If you want to transform each item in a collection, you should use `_.map`:

```js
var results = _.map($('.item'), function(item) {
  return item.value;
});
$('.result').text(JSON.stringify(results));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="item" value="1"/>
  <input type="text" class="item" value="2"/>
  <input type="text" class="item" value="3"/>
</form>
<div class="result"></div>
```

jQuery [also has a map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function which you can use instead of lodash, if you like.

Comment: If it's just a property value you're after, you can use the _property_ shorthand: `_.map($('.item'), 'value');`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need input values it is better to use _.map instead of _.filter

```
_.map($('.date-field'), function(n) {  return n.value });
```

Answer (score -2):

You need a traditional array. Try using [**get()**](https://api.jquery.com/get/) and `value`

```
_.filter($('.date-field').get(), function(n) { return n.value });
```

**Update**

```
var dates = [];
$('.date-field').each(function(){
    dates.push($(this).val());
});
//you can use the date values here with dates
```

Comment: still getting `Uncaught TypeError: n.val is not a function`

Comment: @ChrisYeung, can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: @ChrisYeung, try my answer now

Comment: @ChrisYeung, yes `_.filter` will return the whole element. If you only want the values, you need a different approach. If you can get a fiddle working, I can better help